# What is the significance of slashes in git repository names?

Tags: git, gitosis

I haven't been able to find this explained anywhere, so it probably means that if I was thinking about this issue correctly it would be obvious.  Please set me straight.

When I create a repository 'Project' on my gitosis server, I can access it with the URL `git@server:Project.git`.  Which works great.

Yet, I also see URLs of the form `git@server:Directory/Project.git`.  Is there any special significance to the `Directory/` portion of the URL?  Does this create/imply a submodule? Or is it just a garden variety repository that I can treat like any other?

If I want to group my repositories on my gitosis server this way, can I simply add them to the gitosis conf file like so:

```
[group a_group]
writable = Foo/Bar
members = Me You SomeGuy
```

Thanks for clearing this up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's just a path to the Git repository. Instead of being at, e.g., `~git/Project.git`, it's at `~git/Directory/Project.git`.

Comment: Thanks, I thought that might be the case, but I couldn't find anything that spelled it out. I really didn't want to dig in the source code to find out.